# Performace issue with JSP page load in Enterprise web application

Tags: java, performance, jsp, web, response

I am assigned to a J2EE enterprise web application project. Now the main objective is to resolve some performance issues. it is built on SunOne App. Server (Web & EJB containers) & J2SE 1.4. The problem is with JSP pages response time. They are very very slow. First time, JSP page takes about/more than 1 minute to load and when I click on it, its so much frustrating. So I can imagine the user's expierence. Even, in test environment where I am testing it alone,, take lots of time (regardless of number of concurrent access). After lot of time, JSP page load and it renders mainly 3-4 big drop-down which gets populated from postgres database.

Please suggest me where should I start to identify the performance issues and how can I fix them. I really want to improve the response time and performance of this application.

Answer (score 0):

First: turn on all the logging, then use a debugger & profiler to check what exactly is happening.

Also check what kind of queries are send to the database and try to figure out what is causing the big delay.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to do this. Will let you know about my progress. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Trying setting up your servlet container's config files to precompile the JSPs.

See:

[Removing Performance Bottlenecks Through JSP Precompilation](http://weblogic.sys-con.com/node/42878)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will try this and keep on posted my doubts.